# The algebra $Z(A)/J(Z(A))$ is a product of field extensions of $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. If $A$ is split, then $Z(A)$ is split.(Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. We say that $A$ is split if $\operatorname{End}_A(S) \cong k$ for every simple $A$-module $S$, or equivalently, if $A/J(A)$ is a direct product of matrix algebras over $k$.)

In the proof, the author says The algebra $Z(A)/J(Z(A))$ is a product of field extensions of $k$.

To me, this comes out of blue and I have no clue why field extensions. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $B=Z(A)$ is a finite-dimensional commutative algebra over $k$. Then $B/J(B)$
is a semisimple finite-dimensional commutative algebra over $k$. Applying Wedderburn's theorem, $B/J(B)$ is a product of matrix algebras over division algebras containing
$k$ in their centres. But as everything is commutative, these division algebras are fields and the matrix algebras are all one-dimensional.

Comment: sorry question. why the matrix algebras are 1-dimensional?

Comment: You know that $2\times 2$ matrices may not commute...

Comment: so the commutativity implies both division algebra being fields and matrices being size 1.